Converting time saved as character into time type, but keeping only hours
How can I keep just H:M:S (and discard the automatically inserted date) after converting a data frame field that containted just "hours:minutes" and was formerly of type character?
This is my code
mdp$time <- strptime(mdp$time,'%H:%M')

mdp is a data.frame and the field time contains hours in format HH:MM

Base R doesn't have a native data type for just time. It has a date time type, so a date is always included. I'm not sure if your H:M is a time or a duration. The lubridate package has a functions for durations. It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.
